# C++ error: object of abstract class type is not allowed: pure virtual function has no overrider

Tags: c++

Having trouble with inheritance. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**FigureGeometry.h**

```
    #ifndef FIGUREGEOMETRY
#define FIGUREGEOMETRY

static const float PI = 3.14159f;

class FigureGeometry
{

public:
    virtual float getArea() const = 0;
    virtual float getPerimeter() const = 0;
};

#endif
```

**Circle.h**

```
    #ifndef CIRCLE
#define CIRCLE

#include "FigureGeometry.h"

class Circle:public FigureGeometry
{
    float radius;
public:
    Circle(float theRadius)
    {
        radius = theRadius;
    }
    float getRadius() {return radius;}
    float getArea() {return getRadius() * getRadius() * PI;}
    float getPerimeter() {return getRadius() * 2 * PI;}
};

#endif
```

and then in main.cpp, on the line containing `"Circle c1(5);"` I get the error:

```
21  IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "Circle" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "FigureGeometry::getArea" has no overrider
            pure virtual function "FigureGeometry::getPerimeter" has no overrider   c:\Users\moog\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\data structures 3\data structures 3\main.cpp    9   9   data structures 3
```

Comment: `getArea()` and `getArea() const` are two different functions.

Answer (score 16):

Your functions should be:-

```
float getArea() const {return getRadius() * getRadius() * PI;}
float getPerimeter() const {return getRadius() * 2 * PI;}
```

REASON FOR THIS BEHAVIOR :-

When you re-define a function in derived class with same parameters as in base class then that's called as overriding.
Whereas if you re-define that function with different parameter then it would be an attempt to use overloading from you side. But overloading is possible only in class scope. So, in this case corresponding base class function would be hidden.

For e.g:- Below is futile attempt on overloading.

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void display () const;
};

class Derived 
{
public:
   virtual void display ();
};

int main()
{
    const Derived d;
    d.display();           //Error::no version defined for const....
}
```

So you are getting error as display in derived would hide display in base.

Similarly your pure virtual function would be hidden i.e compiler treat that case as there is no function defined in derived corresponding to base class pure virtual function.That would make derived also a abstract class.

Hope things are crystal clear...

Comment: Function overloading is possible outside of class scope as well.

Comment: O.K so what do you think the reason for this could be?

Comment: The non-const method doesn't override the const one in the base class (because of differing const-qualification), but since it has the same name it *hides* the one in the base class. Since it's not overriden, the derived class becomes abstract.

Comment: So far so good...But that's what I am asking why it hides that??? just because of same name. What I believe is functions with same name and one with const is a good candidate for overloading...Isn't it???

Comment: Please try to compile above example...it should compile properly had overloading across class scopes been allowed...and please give me proper reason as why it's not compiling

Comment: I also apologize for previous example as it didn't demonstrate my concept clearly...

Comment: Those two functions *are* good candidates for overloading, but the Standard chooses not to allow that behavior (by default) because it can cause unexpected behavior in certain circumstances. So instead of overloading it hides the base class functions. You can pull those hidden functions in with a `using Base::display`. Also, your example won't compile because `Derived` needs a user-provided constructor. If you add that it will work (by "work" I mean cause the expected error) -- http://rextester.com/JZBTCZ77777

Answer (score 4):

Your `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` methods do not override the virtual methods declared in `FigureGeometry` because they do not match in `const`-qualification. Therefore `Circle` becomes abstract since those methods were pure virtual; and you can't create objects of abstract type.

To fix this, simply add `const` to both of your methods. Also, to make sure you have correctly overrided methods from the base class, use the `override` specifier:

```c++
float getArea() const override;
float getPerimeter() const override;
```

If they do not override the compiler will let you know with an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place qualifier `const` for these virtual functions in the derived class. Write

```
float getArea() const {return getRadius() * getRadius() * PI;}
float getPerimeter() const {return getRadius() * 2 * PI;}
```

So in fact in the derived class you declared new functions that hide virtual functions in the base class with the same name.

Also you should to declare the destructor also as virtual. For example

```
class FigureGeometry
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual ~FigureGeometry() = default;
};
```

Or

```
class FigureGeometry
{
public:
    // ...
    virtual ~FigureGeometry() {}
};
```