# Pure virtual function has no overrider in Bank Class

Tags: c++, oop, virtual

I'm trying to make an object orientated program that asks a user to become a customer of a bank. However I keep getting this error message in my main file:

object of abstract class type "CommBank" is not allowed:C/C++(322)
main.cpp(36, 28): pure virtual function "Bank::generatePay" has no overrider

Here is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Bank.h"
#include "CommBank.h"
#include "ANZ.h"
#include "NAB.h"
#include "Westpac.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Create a person and ask for their name
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    Person person(name);

    cout << "Welcome, " << person.getName() << "!" << endl;

    // Let the person pick a bank
    cout << "Choose a bank: " << endl;
    cout << "1. CommBank" << endl;
    cout << "2. ANZ" << endl;

    int bankChoice;
    cout << "Enter the number of the bank you want to choose: ";
    cin >> bankChoice;

    Bank* selectedBank;

    if (bankChoice == 1) {
        selectedBank = new CommBank();
    } else if (bankChoice == 2) {
        selectedBank = new ANZ();
    } else if (bankChoice == 3) {
        selectedBank = new NAB();
    } else if (bankChoice == 4) {
        selectedBank = new Westpac();
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid bank choice. Exiting." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a customer
    Customer customer(person.getName());
    customer.setBank(selectedBank->getName());

    cout << "You are now a customer of " << customer.getBank() << endl;

    // Take out a loan
    float loanAmount;
    cout << "Enter the loan amount you want to take out: ";
    cin >> loanAmount;

    customer.setLoan(loanAmount);

    cout << "You have taken a loan of $" << customer.getLoan() << endl;

    // Transfer money from pay into the account
    float weeklyPay;
    cout << "Enter your weekly pay: $";
    cin >> weeklyPay;

    Account account;
    account.setBalance(weeklyPay);

    cout << "Your account balance is $" << account.getBalance() << endl;

    // Display customer and account information
    customer.showInfo();
    account.showInfo();

    // Clean up allocated memory
    delete selectedBank;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my header file for CommBank:

```
#ifndef COMMBANK_H
#define COMMBANK_H

#include <string>
#include "Bank.h"
#include "Account.h"

class CommBank : public Bank {

    protected:
        Account** newAccount;
        float interestRate;
    
    public:
        CommBank();
        CommBank(float capacity);
        
        void generatePay(int accountNumber);
        float generateLoan(float loan, int accountNumber);
        void updateLoan(float amount, int accountNumber);
        void generateInterest(float weeklyPay);

        void addAccount(Account** extraAccount);

        ~CommBank();


};


#endif
```

Here is my Bank.h file:

```
#ifndef BANK_H
#define BANK_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Bank {

    protected:
        string name;
        float capacity;
        int numAccounts;

    public:
        Bank();
        Bank(string name);

        virtual void generatePay() = 0;
        virtual float generateLoan();
        virtual void updateLoan();
};

#endif
```

And here is my Bank.cpp file:

```
#include "Bank.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Bank::Bank() {
    name = "";
    capacity = 0;
    numAccounts = 1;
}

Bank::Bank(string name) {
    this->name = name;
    capacity = 0;
    numAccounts = 1;
}

void Bank::generatePay() {
    return;
}

float Bank::generateLoan() {
    return;
}

void Bank::updateLoan() {
    return;
}
```

I have tried declaring the functions to override but no change.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This `void generatePay(int accountNumber);` has a different signature than `virtual void generatePay()` so it does not override it.  So no override exists.  So you get the error saying no override exists.  In fact none of the three virtuals are overridden because you added a parameter to the new versions.

Comment: [When you re-define a function in derived class with same parameters as in base class then that's called as overriding. Whereas if you re-define that function with different parameter then it would be an attempt to use overloading from you side.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825203/12002570)